DIN 46228-1 technical standard (uninsulated ferrules) - only paid version available?
Question is regarding DIN 46228-1 technical standard (uninsulated ferrules)  - only paid version available or it is publicly available? Why these kind of standards are not public?

I’m voting to close this question because the reasoning behind the monetization of standards is not an Engineering question (electrical or otherwise).

DIN (or ISO) standards are typically never available for free. The reason why is because it costs money to develop, maintain, translate and publish standards...
There are a few exceptions where EU funds certain standardization like the EN/ETSI ones, which are available for free.
